# Estimating an $n$-Gram model using on bigrams

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing

One of the main arguments against $n$-gram models is that, as $n$ increases, there is no way to compute $P(w_n|w_1,\cdots,w_{n-1})$ from training data (since the chance of visiting $w_n,...,w_1$ is practically zero).

Wondering why we cannot estimate $P(w_n|w_1,\cdots,w_{n-1})$ using the following:

Let $P_i(u|v)$ be the probability of having sequences where word $u$ comes exactly $i$ words after word $v$ (This is easy to compute).

Then we can esitmate $P(w_n|w_1,\cdots,w_{n-1})$ as a function of $P_i(u|v)$. I could not find any reference to such approach in the literature. The most similar approach is the smoothing/backoff methods.

Is there any reason why no-one used this approach? Or if one can share some previous work about this approach.

P.S.1. The disadvantage of this approach, comparing with standard $n$-gram model, is its running time.

P.S.2. We could use bucketing idea: Instead of computing/storing/using $P_i$, for every $i$, we can compute/store/use $PB_{i}=P_{2^i}$ . Then $P_i(u|v) \approx PB_{\log i}(u|v)$.

Comment: There is another downside to your suggested approach. It is not as representationally powerful as standard $n$-grams. For example, consider 3-grams on the alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ where the third value is always equal to the XOR of the first 2. With 3-grams, we can represent this, but with your suggested approach, we cannot. It's a bit more like a Naive Bayes-version in that respect. It might work well enough in practice, though.

Comment: @RobbyGoetschalckx That's right: As I said, the proposed approach is an estimator for n-gram model.